# HTML table header sticky bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]I have a bootstrap table, where I am trying to stick the header with position: sticky and top:0. It works, however when I scroll vertically the  of the table body gets imposed on the header. How can I fix this?

HTML
The TH has inline CSS for position sticky and top 0

```
<body class="profilebody">
  <h5 style="text-align: center; font-size: 25px;font-family: 'Alegreya SC', serif;color: #40FF40; padding-left: 25px;"> Updated&nbsp &nbsp Rankings</h5>
  <div class="tablewrapper4">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-dark" id="myTable">
      <thead style="text-align:center; color:#40FF40">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" style="position:sticky; top:0">ID</th>
          <th scope="col" style="position:sticky; top:0">Name</th>
          <th scope="col" style="position:sticky; top:0">Points</th>
          <th scope="col" style="position:sticky; top:0">Edition5 Rank</th>
          <th scope="col" style="position:sticky; top:0">Rank</th>
          <th scope="col" style="position:sticky; top:0">Change</th>
          <th scope="col" style="position:sticky; top:0">Matches Remaining</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <% playerdata[1].forEach(function(player){ %>
      <tr style="text-align:center; color:#40FF40">
        <td><%=player.Player_ID%></td>
        <td><%=player.Player_Name%></td>
        <td><%=player.Total_Weighted_Points%></td>
        <td><%=player.Edition_5_Rank%></td>
        <td><%=player.Rank%></td>
        <td><% if(player.Edition_5_Rank > player.Rank) { %>
          <% var rankdifference = player.Edition_5_Rank - player.Rank %>
          <span> Rank: &#8657 <%=rankdifference%> </span>
          <% } else if(player.Edition_5_Rank < player.Rank) { %>
            <% var rankdifference = player.Rank - player.Edition_5_Rank %>
            <span> Rank: &#8659 <%=rankdifference%> </span>
            <% } else { %>
              <% var rankdifference = 0 %>
              <span> Rank: &#8660 <%=rankdifference%> </span>
              <% } %></td>
          <td>
            <%var remainingames = 9 - player.Edition6_MatchesPlayed%>
            <%=remainingames%></td>
      </tr>
      <% }) %>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
.tablewrapper4 {
  height: 580px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Can someone help, please? Is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

It works if you scroll with `table` instead of `.tablewrapper4` because  `table` elements cannot be split.

```css
body {
  padding-bottom: 1000px;
}
table {
  height: 580px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: pink;
}
th {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body class="profilebody">
  <h5 style="text-align: center; font-size: 25px;font-family: 'Alegreya SC', serif;color: #40FF40; padding-left: 25px;"> Updated&nbsp &nbsp Rankings</h5>
  <div class="tablewrapper4">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-dark" id="myTable">
      <thead style="text-align:center; color:#40FF40">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" style="position:sticky; top:0">ID</th>
          <th scope="col" style="position:sticky; top:0">Name</th>
          <th scope="col" style="position:sticky; top:0">Points</th>
          <th scope="col" style="position:sticky; top:0">Edition5 Rank</th>
          <th scope="col" style="position:sticky; top:0">Rank</th>
          <th scope="col" style="position:sticky; top:0">Change</th>
          <th scope="col" style="position:sticky; top:0">Matches Remaining</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <% playerdata[1].forEach(function(player){ %>
      <tr style="text-align:center; color:#40FF40">
        <td><%=player.Player_ID%></td>
        <td><%=player.Player_Name%></td>
        <td><%=player.Total_Weighted_Points%></td>
        <td><%=player.Edition_5_Rank%></td>
        <td><%=player.Rank%></td>
        <td><% if(player.Edition_5_Rank > player.Rank) { %>
          <% var rankdifference = player.Edition_5_Rank - player.Rank %>
          <span> Rank: &#8657 <%=rankdifference%> </span>
          <% } else if(player.Edition_5_Rank < player.Rank) { %>
            <% var rankdifference = player.Rank - player.Edition_5_Rank %>
            <span> Rank: &#8659 <%=rankdifference%> </span>
            <% } else { %>
              <% var rankdifference = 0 %>
              <span> Rank: &#8660 <%=rankdifference%> </span>
              <% } %></td>
          <td>
            <%var remainingames = 9 - player.Edition6_MatchesPlayed%>
            <%=remainingames%></td>
      </tr>
      <% }) %>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: @SandeepNair How do you mean it? What is overlapping?

Comment: i added a pic @Jax-p for you to have a look

Comment: Oh yea I see. 1) set `background-color` for each `th` column, 2) make sure th has larger `z-index`.

Comment: tried both. still not working. Gave the sticky TH element a z-index of 1. But the overlapping still exists. :). Any other ideas?

Comment: @SandeepNair updated my code snippet. Everything seems fine even without z-index.

Comment: is that padding-bottom on the body required?

Comment: @SandeepNair No. It's used only for example.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding `z-index: 1` to the sticky element? The `z-index` assigns the order of the element. Using `z-index: -1` would mean that it would become underneath another element. [More about z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)